# observer javascript proplem

Tags: javascript, if-statement, frontend, observable, parent-child

i want to add an observer so it can add a class when viewed and remove it when it get out of view
what is wrong?
the proplem is : The code adds the class but doesnt remove The class when the section gets out of viewed

```
const options = {
    threshold: 0.75,
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (enteries ,observer) {
    enteries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting > 0) {
            entry.target.classList.add("StyleSection");
            console.log(entry.target);
           
        }
        else if (entry.isIntersecting === 0){
            sections.classList.remove("StyleSection");
            console.log(entry.target);
            observer.unobserve(section);
        }
        
    });
}, options);`enter code here`
sections.forEach(section => {
    observer.observe(section);
});
```

Comment: *"but doesnt remove it when it get out of viewed"* Then I guess the code is not correct. `sections.classList.remove("StyleSection");` seems wrong, why is that not `entry.target.classList.remove("StyleSection");`, like in the other case? What is `sections`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment and complete the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Explain your expected behavor and what error occours.